# Can two cipher letters per plaintext letter easily defeat character frequency analysis?

Tags: cryptanalysis, classical-cipher

For a class 5 years ago I wrote a paper about *"defeating character frequency analysis by using  two cipher letters per plaintext letter"* (jamesjava.blogspot.com/2009/08/defeating-character-frequency-analysis.html).

Quote:

> Using two letters in the cipher text for each letter in the plaintext can be a good way to create a flat character distribution.
>
> The algorithm is to partition the 676 2-letter combinations based on the standard character frequency. i.e. if the standard frequency for a letter is 5% then it will get 5% of the 2-letter combinations (randomly selected). This doubles the size of the data, could include spaces & punctuation, and makes a much larger key.
>
> Note that some letters may get dropped because they occur less than 1/676 (0.15%) of the time. Both 1-gram and 2-gram frequency analysis produce a nearly uniform histogram (variation appears to only be caused by rounding). Two-gram results: P&P=5,117%; SH=5,013%.
>
> Therefore this technique was extremely effective with no obvious weaknesses.

I didn't get much feedback from the professor so I wonder if anyone can comment on this and tell me if my conclusion is correct.

Comment: Sounds like a [homophonic substitution cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher#Homophonic_substitution).

Comment: An extensive analysis of homophonic substitution ciphers can be found in this paper: [*Efficient Cryptanalysis of Homophonic Substitution Ciphers*](http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/faculty/stamp/RUA/homophonic.pdf)

Comment: Could you copy the relevant paragraph from your paper into your question? This makes it easier to reference it in an answer.

Comment: Given sufficient ciphertext, you can still do frequency analysis. All you did was make the alphabet much larger.

Comment: Antimony: How can you use frequency analysis if the frequencies are uniform? Or how would a larger cipertext produce less uniform frequencies?

Comment: It depends. if 2-letters theme selves have some relation in frequencies, it's possible with a frequency analysis to approach to break the cipher.

Comment: @JamesA.N.Stauffer Given a large enough ciphertext, bigrams and trigrams may still be analyzed. English text consists of roughly 1.5% "th" bigrams, for instance. Based on character frequency, there would be about 2,680 pairs representing "th". You'd need a plaintext large enough to reliably detect quartets occurring 0.00055% of the time, which isn't really all that large.

Answer (score 3):

It is probably impossible to remove language characteristics completely with a substitution cipher. Your algorithm flattens out single character frequencies, but that's it kinda.

Language bigrams (your cipher-quadruples) might not be uniform distributed. The reason for this is simple: Bigram probability is not just the product of the probabilities of both letters - they are not independent variables.

Let's make an example (frequencies from http://www.cryptograms.org/letter-frequencies.php):

- Letter **t** with frequency 0.09056 => 61 cipher-bigrams for **t**
- Letter **h** with frequency 0.06094 => 41 cipher bigrams for **h**
- Bigram **th** with frequency 0.03882
- Now there are $61*41=2501$ cipher quadruples for the original bigram **th**, and all of them have the same probability. However, $2501$ of $26^4 = 456976$ possible qudruples is just a fraction of 0.005473. So now the number of ciphertext quadruples for **th* does not match required number to enforce a uniform distribution.

An other way to attack might work with those bigrams which are very unlikely or even impossible in English language.